# Sound Source Localization with 3 Respeaker 4 Mic array and ODAS

Tags: javascript, audio, localization

I'm working on a project of sourd source localization.
I got 3 Respeaker 4 Mic Array and using [ODAS](https://github.com/introlab/odas) I have to find the coordinates of the source sound.

I make a TCP server to receive the data from the SSL of ODAS, so I got XYZ coordinates (Between -1 and 1 ??) and E (elevation) which is, if I understood correctly the energy.

With this I manage to find how to calculate the azimut we can get with odas_web
In [this file](https://github.com/introlab/odas_web/blob/master/resources/js/graph.js) I found out how to get an azimut in degrees.

```
var az = Math.atan2(y,x) * 180 / Math.PI
```

I was wondering what was the following formula :

```
var inc = Math.acos(z/Math.sqrt(x*x+y*y+z*z))
```

which is then converted in degrees and substracted to 90

So my main problem here is to find how can I use all the data (xyz coords, energy, azimut and inc) from my 3 Respeaker 4 mic array to calculate the coordinates of the sound source.

To resume here are my questions :

- What is "inc" ?
- How can I calculate the coordinates of the sound source using the data of my 3 Respeaker 4 mic array
  Thank you in advance for your help, it will be very valuable to me and sorry for all english mistakes.

I've asked this on the ODAS' github but nobody replies. So you can reply here or on [the github isssue](https://github.com/introlab/odas/issues/262).

- LePtitMetalleux